# FATAL: cannot request additional shared memory outside shmem_request_hook

Tags: postgresql

I have PostgreSQL 15.3. Then I install pg_stat_monitor.
Then when I restart the database, it can't start with this error:

```
-- Unit postgresql-15.service has begun starting up.
Jun 20 13:58:12 PostgresqlDB01 postmaster[1864274]: 2023-06-20 13:58:12.997 EEST [1864274] LOG:  pgaudit extension initialized
Jun 20 13:58:13 PostgresqlDB01 postmaster[1864274]: 2023-06-20 13:58:12.998 EEST [1864274] FATAL:  cannot request additional shared memory outside shmem_request_hook
Jun 20 13:58:13 PostgresqlDB01 postmaster[1864274]: 2023-06-20 13:58:12.998 EEST [1864274] LOG:  database system is shut down
Jun 20 13:58:13 PostgresqlDB01 systemd[1]: postgresql-15.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 20 13:58:13 PostgresqlDB01 systemd[1]: postgresql-15.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and describe how exactly you installed pg_stat_monitor.